# Is there an stl way of doing a deep copy of a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to get my coworkers to use more algorithms and less explicit loops.  So my coworker has a vector of `shared_ptr`s and is making a copy of that `vector` and the items being pointed at.  He has something like this:

```
dst.clear();
for (size_t i=0; i<src.size(); i++)
{
  std::shared_ptr<Type> pObject(new Type(*src[i]));
  dst.push_back(pObject);
}
```

I'm thinking that this could be better done using `std::copy` with a `std::back_inserter`, but I don't see how to get it to copy the items being pointed at using the stuff currently in the STL.

Could roll my own, but would think that this issue would have come up enough that it would have been dealt with by now.

Comment: First, I'd use `std::make_shared`. Second, if the fundamental reason for using shared pointers in the first place is for polymorphism and you want genuine copies of the derived instances, you have an entire different problem to solve. If you just want another vector of the *same* shared pointers, yet another different problem (but trivial). And for *that* code, I don't see `src` used anywhere in the actual copy (yet its magnitude is suspiciously taking part in the loop limit), so the posted code doesn't make any sense regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig, 1st, there is much about this code I don't like. 2nd, why is getting genuine copies an entirely different problem to solve? That _is_ the problem that I want to solve.  Sorry, you're right that I missed the `*src[i]`, fixed that.

Comment: Genuine copies become a problem when you can have instances of `DerivedOne` and `DerivedTwo` in your collection, referred to with two `std::shared_ptr<SomeBase>`, where `SomeBase` is the polymorphic base of both derivations. Now, make a genuine copy of both using only what you have: two `std::shared_ptr<SomeBase>`. um... yeah. Do you see the problem ? As barry mentioned, a `clone()` method is your way out. In short, there is no universal silver bullet here.

Comment: It's a nice way to write Java using C++ compiler. Genuine STL (aka Alex Stepanov's) solution will be to get rid of the vector of pointers, but it requires much more context about the problem your code tries to solve. Basically, what I am saying, it's an XY problem.

Comment: I see your point @WhozCraig.  However, in this case, only the same type of objects are used, so this is fine.  No slicing will occur.

Comment: @IvanAksamentov-Drop, yeah, I'm not too keen on this, but unfortunately, IIRC, it's a requirement for the type of the base object.  It is not allowed to move in memory or it can cause problems.

Comment: If it isn't allowed to move in memory, you could use a `std::deque<Type>`.  Copying the `deque` will copy all the elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(),
    std::back_inserter(dst),
    [](shared_ptr<Type> const& ptr) {
        return make_shared<Type>(*ptr);
    });
```

With the caveat that if `Type` is polymorphic, this probably does the wrong thing and you'll want to add a `clone()` method or something to that effect.

---

In C++20, this'll look something like:

```
dst = src | ranges::view::transform([](shared_ptr<Type> const& ptr){
                return make_shared<Type>(*ptr);
            })
          | ranges::to<std::vector>;
```

Which you can already get with range-v3 today.

Comment: Note that if `Type` is polymorphic, the code in the original question _also_ does the wrong thing.

Comment: Although the `Type` is polymorphic, in this case, they are still the same type, so it is fine.

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I need.  Thanks.